# How to display highest and lowest points an indicator reaches during a single candle

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to display highest and lowest points an indicator reaches during the formation of a single candle in Pine?

To elaborate, lets imagine I've got the regular RSI indicator with the usual settings: "14" period + "**close**" as the source. While a candle is being formed we'll observe the RSI indicator value & line changing (going up and down depending on where price moves). Once that candle closes, the final RSI indicator value will be printed and it will be based on when and where the candle closed.

What I'd like to plot (ideally, as a line/channel in the same way the RSI line is displayed) are the highest and lowest RSI indicator values reached while that same candle was forming.

Nb: using RSI "14" period + "high"/"low" as source to plot the values I'm after would be incorrect, as I wish to display the highest/lowest values that the RSI reached based on the source being the "**close**" of the candles.

Thanks in advance for your help!